# What is a fast and efficient way to encode/decode integers in interval [1, 10^12]?

Tags: javascript, indexing, integer, decode, encode

I need to be able to decode big indices (integers, maybe even over size 10^12) fast on client side and also want them to be encoded with decent compression rate in files that I store on server side. What do you suggest? Maybe hexadecimals?

Answer (score 0):

The "best" encoding depends on space/speed constrains and distribution of expected values.
If you go for minimum size and have many small numbers, you can go variable-length-encoding [such as the SQLite uses](http://sqlite.org/src4/doc/trunk/www/varint.wiki).

Of course all "best" encoding both size and speed wise are binary data, but your mention of "hexadecimal" in the question gives me the doubt that you have to store numbers *as text*, in that case hexadecimal is common and small enough for many needs (10^12 is just short of 40 bits, so it would be 10 characters in hexadecimal), but if space is important, you better use [base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) or similar encodings.